# Variation of Fermat's little theorem of the form $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

If a natural number $a$ coprime to a prime $p$ satisfies $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p^2$$ then, what can we say about $a$ and $p$ ?

Comment: There is another natural number $b$ with $a=b^p \mod p^2$.

Comment: @MooS Is that number different from $a$? If so, can you please tell me how?

Comment: Meanwhile, Jack M did so.

Comment: Related: a *Wieferich prime* is a prime $p$ such that $2^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod{p^2}$. But only two are known, $1093$ and $3511$. The numbers you ask about are sometimes called "base-$a$ Wieferich primes" and are discussed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime#Base-a_Wieferich_primes

Answer (score 4):

There are primitive roots modulo $p^2$, so let $r$ be such a root, and let $a\equiv r^k$. Then

$$r^{k(p-1)}\equiv 1 \mod p^2$$

Which is equivalent to $k(p-1)$ being divisible by $p(p-1)$ (the order of $r$), which in turn is equivalent to $k$ being a multiple of $p$. Thus $a$ is congruent modulo $p^2$ to one of the numbers $1, r^p, r^{2p}, r^{3p} ...$

Comment: How do you prove that $r \neq a$, otherwise the result would be trivial by multiplying the given congruence by $a$ ?

Comment: @Broly A primitive root modulo $p^2$ by definition has the property that $p(p-1)$ is the smallest exponent making it congruent to $1$, but the definition of $a$ was that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$.

Comment: Just a remark that, if we are looking (mod $p^n$) for $n>2$, then there no longer need be primitive roots when $p=2$.